# Do not understand Filter Expressions on Lookup in TMap

Tags: talend

I have a very simple job with 4 'contact' records, of which 2 of them have an identical email address

[image: mini_Knipsel2.png]
[image: mini_Knipsel3.png]

Now I try to find the records have an identical email record. So I load the contact records twice, then both attach them to a tmap, and use a lookup to match on emailaddress. Using filter expressions, I ensure that I don't compare records with themselves.

[image: mini_Knipsel.png.png]

The result now is that only 1 of the duplicate emails is marked as 'duplicate' and the other records is NOT matched. Does anybody have an idea why?

[image]

Comment: what are your join settings..can you click on settings icon on row2 input..it should list left outer join, inner join, unique rows all rows...use all rows and and left outer join

Comment: @garpitmzn It is on "left outer join". If I switch to "all matches" I get 6 rows returned (which makes sense) but I only want 4, with the indicator whether it has a duplicate email or not... Would that be possible otherwise?

Comment: yes, it should be..you have to apply filter on output data set..you should remove the row1.id!=row2.id filter first...and check the output results..next you should apply filter on test (output dataset) which is on your right side..

Comment: Hmm okay... But why would the Filter on the Lookup not work? How does it function exactly? It does a different thing that I'd expect based on the documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because :

> The Unique match option functions as a Last match. The First match and
>   All matches options function as named.

So if we remove the input filter `row1.id!=row2.id` and just left join the 2 flows and show them, we will get:

```
|=-+------------------+----+-----------------=|
|id|mail              |id_1|mail_1            |
|=-+------------------+----+-----------------=|
|c1|some@mail.com     |c1  |some@mail.com     |
|c2|other@mail.com    |c2  |other@mail.com    |
|c3|identical@mail.com|c4  |identical@mail.com|
|c4|identical@mail.com|c4  |identical@mail.com|
'--+------------------+----+------------------'
```

Note that last 2 rows of the lookup flow does not have the row c3, because Talend fetched the last row that match `identical@mail.com` which is c4.
Now if we filter that by `row1.id!=row2.id` we will get only the third row which is what you have got:

```
|=-+------------------+-----------=|
|id|mail              |isDuplicated|
|=-+------------------+-----------=|
|c1|some@mail.com     |false       |
|c2|other@mail.com    |false       |
|c3|identical@mail.com|true        |
|c4|identical@mail.com|false       |
'--+------------------+------------'
```

What we can do using only one tMap is to obtain all unique mail rows and all occurance of duplicated rows by enabling `all match` option.

```
|=-+------------------+----=|
|id|mail              |isDup|
|=-+------------------+----=|
|c1|some@mail.com     |false|
|c2|other@mail.com    |false|
|c3|identical@mail.com|false|
|c3|identical@mail.com|true |
|c4|identical@mail.com|true |
|c4|identical@mail.com|false|
'--+------------------+-----'
```

Then we can filter this output to get duplicated rows in addition to the initial flow, to fill your exact requirement i dont think we are obliged to join this output again like this :
[image]

To get this output:

```
.--+------------------.
|       unique        |
|=-+-----------------=|
|id|mail              |
|=-+-----------------=|
|c1|some@mail.com     |
|c2|other@mail.com    |
|c3|identical@mail.com|
|c4|identical@mail.com|
'--+------------------'

.--+------------------.
|     duplicated      |
|=-+-----------------=|
|id|mail              |
|=-+-----------------=|
|c3|identical@mail.com|
|c4|identical@mail.com|
'--+------------------'
.--+------------------+------------.
|           isDuplicated           |
|=-+------------------+-----------=|
|id|mail              |isDuplicated|
|=-+------------------+-----------=|
|c1|some@mail.com     |false       |
|c2|other@mail.com    |false       |
|c3|identical@mail.com|true        |
|c4|identical@mail.com|true        |
'--+------------------+------------'
```

Comment: So... the filter is executed áfter the match? I would have expected the other way around. Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: @WillemMulder Edited answer

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! So just to be really sure: the filtering (row1.id!=row2.id) is executed *after* the matching?

Comment: @WillemMulder the filter `row1.id!=row2.id` is applied in the input, in the same tMap we apply the filter `row2.id != null` to get only the duplicated rows and `row2.id != null` to get the four rows with no replications, in the second tMap there is no filtering, just left join.

Comment: what I meant is that in general in a TMap, the Filter Expressions are executed *after* the matching is executed? For example in my original case, the "row1.id!=row2.id" filtering happens *after* it matched the c4 lookup row to main c3 and c4, and then the lookup c4 to main c4 is being filtered out, so isDuplicate returns false. Right?